# setting div width according to the screen size of user

Tags: jquery, width, screen

I am trying to set the width and height of a div exactly equal to the size of my users screen. How can it be done. Should I use jquery ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about some CSS? http://jsfiddle.net/TJGZU/

```
body, html { /* set size of body to full page and remove margins */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div { /* set div to full width and height */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

by css seems ideal as pimvdb has suggested...doing it in jquery would be inline styling which would be a bad practice which can be avoided unless necessary.

by means of jquery:

```
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight =$(window).height();
    $('div').css({'width':windowWidth ,'height':windowHeight });
```

**Edited Part:**

```
var windowWidth = ((parseInt($(window).width())) / 2) - 120;
```

like this whatever height and width seems ideal for you, you can obtain via this.

Comment: hmm... it works fine. But will it vary if the contents of my div get updated through ajax and its height crosses the screen width

Comment: the definitely you need jquery based on your async parameter so accordingly styles should be applied once your dynamic elements are populated..  you can use the above solution by manipulating the width and height according to your need..i have edited my post.

Comment: so, i need to change the height of the div by using jquery, everytime i make an ajax request ??

Comment: not every-time set this variables on page load and assign them, how frequently your div content changes???

Comment: but will $(window).height() return the height required to fit all the contents ???

Comment: you need not set the height scroll would take care of that. The div would be fluid enough to take care of the lengthy content.

Answer (score 0):

below is a sample code for your problem:

```
var windowWidth = ((parseInt($(window).width())) / 2) - 120;
```

Also, note that this answer makes use of jQuery.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack overflow! this has already been added as an answer however